# Java FX bounce ball bounces out of box

Tags: javafx, border, bounce

I am new to JavaFX and I have (hopefully) a simple question that maybe someone can help me out with. I have tried looking for answers online and nothing seems to fit in with what I have.

So basically what I am trying to do is have a ball (in my case its a face) bounce around a pane changing direction whenever it hits the wall - simple enough. I can't seem to figure out why the walls only triggers the left side and top side of the face. (In other words, the Left and top walls trigger the bounce correctly, but the bottom and right walls allow the pane to go through them, making the object bounce when the : 1. left side of face touches right wall or 2. top side of face touches bottom wall. The face itself is bouncing in a BorderPane, if that makes a difference in any of this. It is probably the logic behind the code that I have, which i actually got from a textbook.

Here is the relevant code for this matter:

```
public class BoxPane extends Pane {
    private double radius;
    private double x, y;
    private double dx = 1;
    private double dy = 1;
    private Pane thisPane;
    private Timeline animation;

    public BoxPane(Pane pane)
    {
        getChildren().add(pane);
        thisPane = pane;
        radius = thisPane.getWidth()/2;
        x = radius;
        y = radius;
        animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), e -> moveBall()));
        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play();
    }

    public void increaseSpeed()
    {
        animation.setRate(animation.getRate() + 0.1);
    }
    public void decreaseSpeed()
    {
        animation.setRate(animation.getRate()>0?animation.getRate() - 0.1 :     0);
    }

    protected void moveBall()
    {        
        if((x < radius || x > getWidth() - radius))
        {
            dx *= -1;
        }
        if(y < radius || y > getHeight() - radius) {
            dy *= -1;
        }

        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        thisPane.setTranslateX(x);
        thisPane.setTranslateY(y);
    }  
}
```

I can try to explain if something is not clear in my code. But basically, I took the radius of the object that I am passing in, and create an animation with this. I have methods to increase and decrease speed when a key is pressed (function calls are from a different java file) and moveBall() seems to be where my problem is. 
Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!
I am sorry if this is a repost of something that was already answered, I couldn't seem to find anything that helped me in my specific case. If needed, I can also provide screenshots of what the program actually looks like and where the ball is turning around. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to print the value of radius in moveBall() method, you will notice that its value is always 0. Because you are taking the width of the pane before it is rendered in the scenegraph. To fix this, you can change radius to DoubleProperty and bind its value to the pane width property.

Also there  is small correction required in your moveBall() logic. Please check the below corrections.

```
private DoubleProperty radius = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

public BoxPane(Pane pane) {
    getChildren().add(pane);
    thisPane = pane;
    radius.bind(thisPane.widthProperty().divide(2));
    x = radius.get();
    y = radius.get();
    animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5), e -> moveBall()));
    animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    animation.play();
}

protected void moveBall() {
    double faceWidth = radius.get() * 2;
    if ((x < 0 || x > getWidth() - faceWidth)) {
        dx *= -1;
        if (x < 0) {
            x = 0;
        } else if (x > getWidth() - faceWidth) {
            x = getWidth() - faceWidth;
        }
    }
    if (y < 0 || y > getHeight() - faceWidth) {
        dy *= -1;
        if (y < 0) {
            y = 0;
        } else if (y > getHeight() - faceWidth) {
            y = getHeight() - faceWidth;
        }
    }
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    thisPane.setTranslateX(x);
    thisPane.setTranslateY(y);
}
```

Comment: I added this and it works perfectly! Thank you so much! Could you just explain what the DoublyProperty is doing? I haven't heard of it and online explains it in confusing terms.

Comment: @OscarLopez It's a property wrapper that implements the `Observer` design pattern. In general the binding is observing for changes in the value and will update itself when any change occurs.

Comment: Oh wow, thats interesting. That makes sense! I seem to be getting a small problem when running the code though. When I go to minimize the window, the face gets glitched and gets stuck outside of the boundary. Do you know what I can do to fix this? This only happens when I go to minimize the window

Comment: Not sure about your issue. Because I cannot reproduce that with the demo I had. May be if you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will be helpful for others to see the exact issue.

Comment: Given the new function that was provided, the only problem I face is that when I go to minimize the window, the ball is pushed closer to the walls (obviously), but this allows me to take the ball out of the boundaries of the bane, making it get stuck outside of the boundaries. It will be moving up and down while it shakes uncontrollably. Given exactly what was given in the moveBall() function is what creates this glitch. Any way to fix that? It only happens when I am dragging the window to be smaller. Once I let go, if the ball is still inside the boundaries it continues its bounce.

Comment: Ok now I got what your issue is about. You used the wrong term ;) You should have said "when i decrease the size of the window by resizing.." rather than saying "When i minimize..". Because "minimize" has its own meaning ;)
I will check and will try to figure out.

Comment: Thought I responded but I didn't press send. It works perfectly! Thank you so much!